# Applescript; unable to get elements within window

Tags: outlook, applescript

I am trying to inspect and report the size of a Microsoft Outlook window (v 15.41) on a Mac. I know the window contains a scrollview and a webarea.

```
tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Microsoft Outlook"
            set position of the front window to {10, 10}
            set size of the front window to {1366, 768}
            set i to entire contents of the front window
        end tell
    end tell
```

the above puts in the Result window `{}` despite the window definitely having child controls.

Interestingly, after running that applescript command, the MS Outlook window appears to crash. If I try to inspect known children of the window, the window instantly closes then I receive an error that the child element does not exist. If I try to use 'bounds' instead of the explicit size and position commands, the window crashes. REALLY interestingly, if I use Accessibility inspector, and try to use the mouse cursor to identify window parts, if i hover over the split group/window itself it crashes (but the scroll area at the bottom of the window doesn't). I am wondering if this is a permissions issue somehow?

This is a hard issue to reproduce. I have two macs running the same OS version, one can access the window contents and inspect the front window's children, one cannot. Both are running the same version of Outlook on the same version of OSX.

UPDATE:
I was able to identify the error that occurs when trying to inspect the child elements of the window
https://pastebin.com/5v4jM5aV
I'm also working with the latest from MS, Outlook 16.9

I am now 90% sure this is something to do with permissions. I have three machines, two of which exhibit this behavior. The one that does not is a 2014 Mac on 10.13.3 which I've upgraded OSes from each time. The other two are brand new machines with brand new installs of 10.13.3 and all are running Outloook 16.9

UPDATE 2:
A fresh install of OSX on a different mac mini seems to have resolved the initial applescript issue. However I am seeing weird behavior w/ the `screencapture` utility. See attached file. [image]

Comment: Note that unless the menu bar is hidden, setting `item 2` in the `list` for the `position` or `bounds` _property_, to anything less then 23 doesn't move it to the <23 value in newer versions of the OS or <22 value in older versions of the OS.

Comment: So the issue I'm seeing with the closing window is not related to the bounds values, 10,10 works and the below answer from @wch1zpink works if I do window 1 and not main window 1;

Comment: `set position of the front window to {10, 10}` **only works if the menu bar is hidden!**

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra and Outlook v. 15.13.3

```
property theBounds : {10, 10, 1366, 768}
property uiElems : {}

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set bounds of every window to theBounds
    my getEntireContents()
end tell

on getEntireContents()
    activate application "Microsoft Outlook"
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events"
        tell front window of application process "Microsoft Outlook"
            set uiElems to entire contents
        end tell
    end tell
end getEntireContents
```

---

Here is a little bit of a different spin with the code…  If Microsoft Outlook has multiple windows open, this version will allow you to choose (from a list of open windows), which window to run the script actions on.

```
global resultValue
property theBounds : {10, 10, 1366, 768}
property windowNames : {}
property uiElems : {}

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set windowNames to name of every window
    my chooseFromList()
    try
        set bounds of window (item 1 of resultValue) to theBounds
    end try
    my getEntireContents()
end tell

on getEntireContents()
    activate application "Microsoft Outlook"
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events"
        tell front window of application process "Microsoft Outlook"
            set uiElems to entire contents
        end tell
    end tell
end getEntireContents

on chooseFromList()
    set resultValue to choose from list windowNames ¬
        with title ¬
        "Choose Window To Process" with prompt ¬
        "You want the UI elements of which window?" OK button name ¬
        "OK" cancel button name ¬
        "CANCEL" without empty selection allowed
end chooseFromList
```

Comment: Unfortunately Outloook 15.41 is the version I'm stuck with, it's what Office 365 gives you as a download.

Comment: Here is my total workflow:
Open microsoft outlook. 
Close the main window
Open an .eml file from the desktop, ones one window with the .eml message
run the script you provided
Error message: "Microsoft Outlook got an error: Can't get main window 1. Invalid Index."

Comment: If I switch 'main window 1' to 'window 1', the resize operation happens, but the `entire contents` bit returns `{}` instead of the window's children

Comment: @Richthofen  before I added the delay .5 to the code, i also got the error message "Can't get main window 1. Invalid Index"  Try changing  delay 0.5 to  delay 1 or  delay 1.5.

Comment: I actually open the outlook window by hand, by opening a .eml file, before running the script. Its not a delay of the window opening because the window is open and frontmost before I run the script.

Comment: Check the end of my question; I updated it with specific errors that are closing the outlook window.

Comment: @Richthofen I tweaked the code in my answer slightly.  Then I followed your exact work flow...  I opened Outlook app, then I closed the main window, Then I opened a .eml file which was located on my desktop...  Then I ran my revised code... No errors on my end

Comment: Yeah its something with the system or systems I am testing with... I paved a fresh mac mini with MacOS 10.13.3 then installed outlook and its not happening anymore. Although, this new mini won't capture using 'screencapture' correctly, so eliminated one problem only to replace it with another.